# Embed PWA version of Google Apps into a Nativescript App

Tags: nativescript

I'm a Rails developer and I'm discovering now NativeScript. I know Vue, and looks like NativeScript support Vue.js
As you know Huawei device cannot accesso anymore to Google Play Services, but the web version of the Google Apps, like Youtube, Gmail, Drive still works.

Instead of having a lot of web shortcut on my home screen I think to write a simple NativeScript App where i list on the homescreen some Google Services I need and clicking on an icon, Google Drive for example, I launch drive.google.com inside the WebView. 
Do you think is possibile? Do you see any issue with login?

Comment: I think it's best if you use Chrome Tabs aka [nativescript-advanced-webview](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-advanced-webview) than using simple WebView.

Comment: @Manoj I don't have Chrome, I have the Huawei Browser :-(

Comment: In that case you may use WebView but you will have to enable features as needed, like local storage, implement upload and download of files etc., I bet you would you need them for using Google Drive.